# While loop, a println is double printing

Tags: java

I have an infinite while loop in my code and the thing is if I call the getInput method ("input" case) or resize method ("resize" case, after it executes it prints the command line twice like this:

Enter one of the following commands: input, display, filter, resize or exit

Enter one of the following commands: input, display, filter, resize or exit

This is my code for the loop:

```
while (true) {                                                                                               
    System.out.println("\nEnter one of the following commands: input, display, filter, resize or exit");     
    String command = reader.nextLine();                                                                      

   switch (command) {                                                                                        
       case "input":                                                                                         
            data = getInput(data);                                                                           
            break;                                                                                           
       case "display":                                                                                       
            displayContents(data);                                                                           
            break;                                                                                           
        case "filter":                                                                                       
            data = removeEvens(data);                                                                        
            break;                                                                                           
        case "resize":                                                                                       
            data = resize(data);                                                                             
            break;                                                                                           
        case "exit":                                                                                         
            System.exit(0);                                                                                  
    }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.com. Let's format your code first!

Comment: This doesn't look reproducible to me.  Are you sure what you posted is the actual code which is having this behavior?

Comment: I guess you wanna get user input. Try to use `Scanner`. example: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` `data = scan.nextString();` if data is String type

Comment: so the loop is supposed to call methods depending on the user's input. The code works but I'm having this issue with a double printing "Enter the command" line.. I have no idea where's the issue

Comment: maybe your methods take additional input (for example with `nextInt()`) without reading the final newline at the end of the input. That would lead to `reader.nextLine()` returning an empty string.

Comment: what is `data = getInput(data); ` doing?

Comment: Can you please add the code for the methods you are calling?

Answer (score -1):

The break within the switch breaks from switch. Then the infinite loop continues.

If you want break from the loop, you could use a label.

i.e.

```
INPUT_LOOP:
       while (true) {
           System.out.println("\nEnter one of the following commands: input, display, filter, resize or exit");
           String command = reader.nextLine();

           switch (command) {
           case "input":
               data = getInput(data);
               break INPUT_LOOP;
           case "display":
               displayContents(data);
               break INPUT_LOOP;
           case "filter":
               data = removeEvens(data);
               break INPUT_LOOP;
           case "resize":
               data = resize(data);
               break INPUT_LOOP;
           case "exit":
               System.exit(0);
           }
       }
```